# Is there any way in express to serve ejs files and next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm having an express app that serves EJS files, now i wanted to add one more framework called next js(server side rendering framework). Is there any way of routing that supports next js and ejs through express.

Answer (score 1):

First, create the **views** folder as you would normally do in EJS and then create a SUB-FOLDER within it called **pages** and you can create another sub-folder under views for your **template/partials** folder.

1. I attached 2 images with examples of the folder structures: [Eaxmple 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C7kd.png) [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLUg2.png)
2. You will find a template for the folder structure in this GitHub link:
   https://github.com/petranb2/masterEJS
3. Here is a medium post that details the project implementation of related to the above GitHub template: https://medium.com/swlh/master-ejs-template-engine-with-node-js-and-expressjs-979cc22b69be
4. The link below is a free e-book where you will find an even more detailed example of a project that author converted from just EJS to EJS and Next.js.
   https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785888434/1/ch01lvl1sec12/restructuring-the-views-folder-using-partials

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent solution and posted here the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649819/1014873

In brief, just add the `copy-webpack-plugin` to `next.config.js` so it will copy your desired files/folders to the `.next` output folder

Answer (score 0):

Install following packages:

1. next
2. next-runtime
3. React
4. React-dom

Create pages directory in project's root and create _app.js next root file. Use following sample code in index.js.

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const next = require( 'next' );

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next( { dev } );
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

    

app.prepare().then( () => {
        const server = express();

        server.get('/p/:slug', (req, res) => {
            const actualPage = '/post';
            const queryParams = { title: req.params.slug };
            app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
        });

        /**
         * Wrapping express app inside next will allow us to create routes by using
         * express js function inside of the next js build
         *
         * '*' means all routes which are not explicit , use next page route.
         */
        server.get( '*', ( req, res ) => {
            return apps.render(req, res, `${req.path}`, req.query)
        } );

        server.listen( port, ( err ) => {
            if ( err ) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.warn( `Ready on http://localhost:${port}` );
        } );
    } );
```

Add following in package:

```
"build": "next build",
"start": "node index.js"
```

Also we can configure any templating engine inside

```
app.prepare().then(()=>{
// other express related config

})
```