# Next.js Include template files in server build

Tags: server, build, next.js, assets

How do I tell Next.js to include a set of files or a whole directory in the server build?

In my case, I would like to dynamically import email templates, depending on which one is required. If the `/mail/` folder were copied alongside my `/pages/` folder, the following path would work: `path.resolve(__dirname, "../mails", template + ".ejs")`

Unfortunately (yet logically), this does not work. How do I copy my entire folder (sort of like an asset) without needing to directly reference (`import "mails/*.ejs"`) every file I would like to copy?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @FabioMilheiro Unfortunately, I did not at all so I went with individually importing each file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using email templates in NextJS and I'm astonished as there's not so many people facing this problem... weird, moreover it should be something easy to do!

By the way I found a simple and elegant solution adding the Webpack Copy plugin to NextJS config file (`next.config.js`):

```js
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new (require('copy-webpack-plugin'))({
          patterns: [
            {
              // copy the `templates` folder as-is
              from: 'src/templates/',
              // it will be accessible at `.next/server/templates`
              to: 'templates/',
            },
          ],
        }),
      )
    }
    return config
  },
```

Don't forget to install the package: `copy-webpack-plugin`

For your reference here a *more complete* NextJS config file

```js
// @ts-check
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { env } = require('./src/server/env')

/**
 * Don't be scared of the generics here.
 * All they do is to give us autocompletion when using this.
 *
 * @template {import('next').NextConfig} T
 * @param {T} config - A generic parameter that flows through to the return type
 * @constraint {{import('next').NextConfig}}
 */
function getConfig(config) {
  return config
}

/**
 * @link https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction
 */
module.exports = getConfig({
  /**
   * Dynamic configuration available for the browser and server.
   * Note: requires `ssr: true` or a `getInitialProps` in `_app.tsx`
   * @link https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration
   */
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    sendgridApiKey: process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY,
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NODE_ENV: env.NODE_ENV,
  },
  /** We run eslint as a separate task in CI */
  eslint: { ignoreDuringBuilds: !!process.env.CI },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // add copy webpack plugin
    if (isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new (require('copy-webpack-plugin'))({
          patterns: [
            {
              // copy the templates folder
              from: 'src/templates/',
              to: 'templates/',
            },
          ],
        }),
      )
    }
    return config
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can include templates folder in public folder. And in api use:

```js
import path from 'path';
const templatesFolderPath = path.resolve('./public', 'emailTemplates');
```